# Postgresql limit in string_agg function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a query as follows:

```
SELECT string_agg(sn::text, ','), product_id
  FROM irmsapp_serializedinventory
  group by product_id;
```

The result is an aggregated `sno` field and products. I would like to know if we can limit the concatenations to 5 and leave the rest for the `sno` field. Currently my `sno` field is a big list and i want to reduce it to a list of 5 elements(the first 5 elements in the sorted order).

Comment: the first five elements

Comment: I want them in sorted order..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rows in a relational database are ***not*** "sorted". You need to have some column by which you can sort the result, only then you can specify which rows are the "first five".

Assuming you have e.g. a `created_at` column that defines the "first five", you can do something like this:

```
select string_agg(sno::text, ','), product_id
from (
   select product_Id, sno,
          row_number() over (partition by product_id order by created_at desc) as rn
   from irmsapp_serializedinventory
) t
where rn <= 5
group by product_id;
```

This picks 5 rows **per product**. If you just want 5 rows regardless of the `product_id` then just remove the `partition by product_id` in the window function.

The `order by created_at desc` is what defines the sort order and what defines which five rows are being used in the aggregation.

Comment: hi i have a question. What if my rows are already sorted and i need to get the first 5?

Comment: @RogerFederer: again: rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** "sorted". The only (really: the **only**) way to guarantee a sort order is to use an `order by` there is *no* alternative.